# I want to find capital string from column and if available then pick first three letter and print in lower case

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, xls

I want to find capital string from column and if available then pick first three letter and print in lower case.
Consider i have data in column like:

```
 oracle-DATA-key  --> convert it --> oracle-dat-key
key-JAVABEAN    ---> convert it --> key-jav
```

I am able to find `=NOT(EXACT(LOWER(F5),F5))` which will be true if capital value is available. but this i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the following, which is based purely on first character in cell. Not if you are looking for any occurrence of uppercase.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(CODE(F5)<=90,CODE(F5)>=65),LOWER(LEFT(F5,3)),""),"")
```

A regex function to output a changed string, changing all occurrences

```
Public Function ReplacedString(ByVal r As Range) As String

    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]{2,}"
        outputString = r.Text

        If .test(outputString) Then
            For Each currMatch In .Execute(r.Text)
                outputString = Replace(outputString, currMatch.Value, LCase$(Left(currMatch, 3)))
            Next currMatch
        Else
            ReplacedString = r.Text
        End If
    End With

    ReplacedString = outputString

End Function
```

And looping a target column using the function:

```
Public Sub ReplaceStrings()
    Const columnToReplaceIn = 1                  'e.g. A
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   'change as appropriate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Columns(columnToReplaceIn), .UsedRange)
            rng.Value = ReplacedString(rng)
        Next rng
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function ReplacedString(ByVal r As Range) As String

    With New RegExp 'CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")   ''Late binding if not Microsoft vbscript regular expressions referenc
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]{2,}"
        outputString = r.Text

        If .test(outputString) Then
            For Each currMatch In .Execute(r.Text)
                outputString = Replace(outputString, currMatch.Value, LCase$(Left(currMatch, 3)))
            Next currMatch
        Else
            ReplaceString = r.Text
        End If
    End With

    ReplacedString = outputString

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you it work with first three ..but i want find any occurrence of uppercase

Comment: I have updated. This code would go in a standard module. If you use the function by itself then you can type into a cell in the adjacent column  e.g. in B1, to get replaced string using A1 put =ReplacedString(A1). If running the sub, it will do the replacements in place e.g. will replace the existing cell values in the specified column.

Answer (score 0):

You have given very small data-set to test with. Here's a preliminary concept which uses RegExp

```
Public Function ReplaceFirstCaps(strInput As String) As String
Dim oM As Object
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]{3,}"
    If .Test(strInput) Then
        Set oM = .Execute(strInput)
        ReplaceFirstCaps = Replace(strInput, oM(0), LCase(Left(oM(0), 3)), , , vbBinaryCompare)
    Else
        ReplaceFirstCaps = strInput
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Then use it in sheet like:

`=ReplaceFirstCaps(A2)`